# What is continuous tense of wear? | metal parts wearing or metal parts wear

Tags: tenses, continuous-aspect

I'm not a native English speaker, and I have a doubt about the continuous tense of the word 'wear'.

What is the correct sentence out of these two?

> Lubricant oils help to reduce metal parts wearing.
>
> Lubricant oils help to reduce metal parts wear.

Comment: The object of a verb is a noun whenever possible, so what you should do instead of worry about gerunds and whatnot is to use a noun, and just say _help to reduce wear on metal parts_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Lubricant oils help to reduce metal parts wearing.
> Lubricant oils help to reduce metal parts wear.

The idea of tense is not involved here; the ending "-ing" by itself is not an indication of tense, and it is not even an indication that a verbal form is being used; in this case, "wearing", which is also in other constructions the present participle of "wear", is not the verb but a noun. The past participle is treated as a noun in some syntactic contexts, such as the present one.

> (SOED) **wearing** n.  **1**  *gen* The action of WEAR¹.

In this sentence, "WEAR" means on the whole "waste away, decay" (SOED), and more precisely "(SOED) become impaired, or decay gradually from friction, use, attrition, etc. (also foll. by *away, down, out*)".

"Wear", as used in the second sentence is a noun defined as follows.

> (SOED) **wear¹** v. **4** The process or condition of being worn or impaired by continued use, friction, attrition, etc.; deterioration of quality due to this.

There is a subtle difference between the two; whereas the use of "wearing" shows that we are looking at the phenomenon from the point of view that the action is that of the part, "wear" shows that we are looking at it from the point of view that the degradation is due to a process acting on the part. Both say the same thing, however; the outcome is the same.

Comment: Would the downvoters say what is wrong with this answer?